# What is wrong with my MINA message? Going over a NioSocketConnector and failing, causing MINA to stop

Tags: java, nio, messaging, apache-mina

I have a `NioSocketConnector`, and have successfully gotten the `IoSession`.  I can write test messages (`"abcdef"`, `"|"`, `"(asdfb)"`, `"1234567890"`, etc.)  My "real" messages error and cause the connection to shut down (literally, the session closes).

My "real" message:
`05082013113112272|123.123.123.0|0.0.0.0|ABC|21|AGG=1=29=299|3e8c288afe77ae0f2ae8d2549f90156`

I can get the following through:

- `2013111211781|123.123.123.0|0.0.0.0|ABC|21|AGG=1=29=299|3e8c288afe77ae0f2ae8d2549f90156`
- `2013|05082013111211781|123.123.123.0|0.0.0.0|ABC|21|AGG=1=29=299|3e8c288afe77ae0f2ae8d2549f90156`
- `//05082013121502688|123.123.123.0|0.0.0.0|AGG=1=2=23|5ca5905b75c6643bddb64be055c3f236`
- `20130501202445`  (but not `2013050**8**1202445`)

I'm using UTF-8. It appears that I'm hitting some kind of length issue--or some kind of magical string scan.  Since I'm starting with numbers, could there be a trigger that the data is binary and then fails some checksum?
Could someone please help me out?  I don't understand what it is that I'm hitting.

Comment: Right now I'm testing through. I can add "//" to get the original message through. (Messy, but workable)  When I attempt to narrow down the string, I can go to "0508201312024453" and that fails.  I'm not sure why though.  I'm still using UTF-8.  None of the characters are weird.  And this seems a bit specific to be some kind of "do something strange if you see this error code" type thing.....  Ideas are always welcome!

Comment: OK.  NOw I'm even more stumped.  1234567812345678 worked.  0123456701234567 worked.  The second round with 1234567812345678 failed.

Comment: I have added a custom protocol decoder/encoder. I am adding some start/end stuff and still nothing.

Comment: Is there a reason that the NioSocketConnector dies on the first message?

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by another issue.  The strings had nothing to do with the closing of the connection.